# Failed and Pending updates: "restart your computer to install important updates"?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I have a windows 7 laptop with a bunch of pending and failed updates (2009 HP, i3).

[image]

When I manually download them (e.g. [January, 2017 Security Monthly Quality Rollup for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB3212646)](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/search.aspx?q=3212646)) and try to install the [.msu](http://download.windowsupdate.com/c/msdownload/update/software/secu/2017/01/windows6.1-kb3212646-x64_a94cf69326099fb121cdd7daf9dfc558f740afb8.msu) file, the installer tells me the update is already on the computer.

[image]

How can I get this (and other) pending updates to install? Per [Windows Update: FAQ](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12373/windows-update-faq), should I "uninstall" pending and failed updates prior to manually installing them?

For what it is worth, there are no "hidden updates" reported by the Windows Updater Control Panel. also, if I leave the Windows Updater preference in the "automatically download and install" mode I am constantly reminded to restart, yet the restart rarely actually installs anything.

[image]

When the "Shutdown" option has a yellow shield icon next to it, then something actually does get installed upon restarting.

[image]
[image]

The install history goes back to 2011 and prior to the 08/2015 release of the "Upgrade to Windows 10" there were only 5 failed update installations (3 "important" and 2 "recommended"). Not including the failed "Upgrade to Windows 10" installs, there are a total of 14 Failed updates and 100+ Pending updates since 08/2015. How should I address all these pending and failed updates to get my OS current and the Windows Updater messages relevant?

---

**UPDATE**

"Fix Problems with Windows Update" from Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Troubleshooting (with Administrator privileges) checks for updates and then upon it's suggestion to open Windows Update, I am told to Restart for pending changes. I restart... nothing changes.  Of note - the "Recent Check For Updates" does not indicate a recent check.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

It is now 7AM and the midnight timestamp was from when I first wrote this question. This makes sense as the Troubleshooting report indicates that searching for updates failed (Despite the earlier indication that the troubleshooter "ran successfully").

[image]

...and as much as I like to "explore"

[image]

"Exploring Additional Options" is what led me here in the first place.

[image]

As for the link to the [online troubleshooting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10164/fix-windows-update-errors), I have now confirmed that I have no network problems causing this issue, and that the downloadable version of the Windows Update Troubleshooter ([WindowsUpdate.diagcab](http://aka.ms/diag_wu)) is as ineffectual as the one I already have in my Control Panel:

[image]

Sure, it says "Fixed" however the Jan 2017 Security Monthly Quality Rollup is still pending - tho now the Version history log reports "Never" for the latest install and check... Continuing the dialogue with the [online troubleshooting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10164/fix-windows-update-errors) the suggestion is to re-install the OS. This seems like a ridiculous option.

As for "Windows Update error 0x80070490" I am looking into these procedures to address it:

1. http://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-update-error-0x80070490
2. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-update/how-do-i-fix-error-code-0x80070490windows-update/38fa3ffc-6361-4c14-83d3-13bc5c3a9047

per http://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-update-error-0x80070490:

> 1] [...] If you are running Windows 7 or Windows Vista, after running the
>   [System File Checker](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-run-system-file-checker-analyze-its-logs-in-windows-7-vista), you should use the [System Update Readiness Tool](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/checksur-system-update-readiness-tool)
>   to repair Windows Update.
>
> 2] If this does not help, create a new User Account and see if that
>   works for you.
>
> 3] You need to also ensure that your Windows Update Service,
>   Background Intelligent Transfer Service and Cryptographic Service are
>   running properly. To do this, open Run box, type services.msc and hit
>   Enter to open the Services manager. Here you can check the status of
>   each of these services. Ensure that they are started. Windows Update
>   at Automatic (Trigger Start), BITS should be set at Automatic
>   (Delayed) and Cryptographic Service at Automatic. Double-clicking on
>   the service name will open up its Properties box that will offer
>   additional options.
>
> 4] Run the Windows Update Troubleshooter and see if that helps.

---

**UPDATE**
[image]
`C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log` is of course a 16MB text file with restrictive permissions... so let me figure out some `grep` options, cuz `cat` has been loading the file for over a minute now :\

...and this is what I get using:
`DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Scanhealth` &
`DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth`

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

Per the comment regarding [the answer suggesting the removal of](https://superuser.com/a/791118/630402) `C:\windows\winsxs\pending.xml`: it's odd, I have two of these files with something appended to the filename, one is 25KB w/a creation and modification date 3/10/2016@2:42AM
`C:\windows\winsxs\pending.xml.01d17ae4bd6c3f2c`
...and the other ~16MB w/a creation and modification date 3/11/2016@2:00PM
`C:\windows\winsxs\pending.xml.01d17bd0c51f9f61`

Removal of these two files from the `C:\windows\winsxs\` directory did not allow for the pending updates to be installed, nor for the control panel to check for pending updates:

[image]

Possibly related there was a failed update on 3/10/2016@10:51AM:

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

Per the `sfc/scannow` CBS.log there seems to be a common thread of "`31bf3856ad364e35`" with, for example:
`Windows7SP1-KB976933~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.17514` &
`Package_for_KB976933~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~fr-FR~6.1.7601.17514`

From the CBS.log, grepping for [0x80070490](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kikag.png):

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> cat C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log | grep 0x80070490
2017-02-09 10:09:34, Info                  CBS    Failed to find package from aggreated XML string, package: Package_for_KB976933~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~fr-FR~6.1.7601.17514 [HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
2017-02-09 10:09:34, Info                  CBS    Failed to find package from deployment update [HRESULT = 0x80070490 -ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
2017-02-09 10:09:34, Error                 CBS    Failed to check whether package is partially installed, package: Windows7SP1-KB976933~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.17514 [HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
2017-02-09 10:09:34, Info                  CBS    Failed to evaluate external applicability for package update: 976933-0_neutral_PACKAGE [HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
2017-02-09 10:09:34, Error                 CBS    Failed to call external evaluate applicability on package: Package_for_KB976932~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.17514, Update: 976933-0_neutral_PACKAGE [HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]

2017-02-09 10:09:43, Info                  CBS    Failed to find package from aggreated XML string, package: Package_for_KB976933~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~fr-FR~6.1.7601.17514 [HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
2017-02-09 10:09:43, Info                  CBS    Failed to find package from deployment update [HRESULT = 0x80070490 -ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
2017-02-09 10:09:43, Error                 CBS    Failed to check whether package is partially installed, package: Windows7SP1-KB976933~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.17514 [HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
2017-02-09 10:09:43, Info                  CBS    Failed to evaluate external applicability for package update: 976933-0_neutral_PACKAGE [HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
2017-02-09 10:09:43, Error                 CBS    Failed to call external evaluate applicability on package: Package_for_KB976932~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.17514, Update: 976933-0_neutral_PACKAGE [HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]

2017-02-09 10:18:51, Info                  CBS    Failed to find package from aggreated XML string, package: Package_for_KB976933~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~fr-FR~6.1.7601.17514 [HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
2017-02-09 10:18:51, Info                  CBS    Failed to find package from deployment update [HRESULT = 0x80070490 -ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
2017-02-09 10:18:51, Error                 CBS    Failed to check whether package is partially installed, package: Windows7SP1-KB976933~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.17514 [HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
2017-02-09 10:18:51, Info                  CBS    Failed to evaluate external applicability for package update: 976933-0_neutral_PACKAGE [HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
2017-02-09 10:18:51, Error                 CBS    Failed to call external evaluate applicability on package: Package_for_KB976932~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.17514, Update: 976933-0_neutral_PACKAGE [HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]

2017-02-09 10:19:02, Info                  CBS    Failed to find package from aggreated XML string, package: Package_for_KB976933~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~fr-FR~6.1.7601.17514 [HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
2017-02-09 10:19:02, Info                  CBS    Failed to find package from deployment update [HRESULT = 0x80070490 -ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
2017-02-09 10:19:02, Error                 CBS    Failed to check whether package is partially installed, package: Windows7SP1-KB976933~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.17514 [HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
2017-02-09 10:19:02, Info                  CBS    Failed to evaluate external applicability for package update: 976933-0_neutral_PACKAGE [HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
2017-02-09 10:19:02, Error                 CBS    Failed to call external evaluate applicability on package: Package_for_KB976932~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.17514, Update: 976933-0_neutral_PACKAGE [HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]

2017-02-09 11:07:06, Info                  CBS    Failed to find package from aggreated XML string, package: Package_for_KB976933~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~fr-FR~6.1.7601.17514 [HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
2017-02-09 11:07:06, Info                  CBS    Failed to find package from deployment update [HRESULT = 0x80070490 -ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
2017-02-09 11:07:06, Error                 CBS    Failed to check whether package is partially installed, package: Windows7SP1-KB976933~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.17514 [HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
2017-02-09 11:07:06, Info                  CBS    Failed to evaluate external applicability for package update: 976933-0_neutral_PACKAGE [HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
2017-02-09 11:07:06, Error                 CBS    Failed to call external evaluate applicability on package: Package_for_KB976932~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.17514, Update: 976933-0_neutral_PACKAGE [HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]

2017-02-09 11:07:15, Info                  CBS    Failed to find package from aggreated XML string, package: Package_for_KB976933~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~fr-FR~6.1.7601.17514 [HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
2017-02-09 11:07:15, Info                  CBS    Failed to find package from deployment update [HRESULT = 0x80070490 -ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
2017-02-09 11:07:15, Error                 CBS    Failed to check whether package is partially installed, package: Windows7SP1-KB976933~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.17514 [HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
2017-02-09 11:07:15, Info                  CBS    Failed to evaluate external applicability for package update: 976933-0_neutral_PACKAGE [HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
2017-02-09 11:07:15, Error                 CBS    Failed to call external evaluate applicability on package: Package_for_KB976932~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.17514, Update: 976933-0_neutral_PACKAGE [HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]

2017-02-09 11:08:18, Info                  CBS    Failed to find package from aggreated XML string, package: Package_for_KB976933~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~fr-FR~6.1.7601.17514 [HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
2017-02-09 11:08:18, Info                  CBS    Failed to find package from deployment update [HRESULT = 0x80070490 -ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
2017-02-09 11:08:18, Error                 CBS    Failed to check whether package is partially installed, package: Windows7SP1-KB976933~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.17514 [HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
2017-02-09 11:08:18, Info                  CBS    Failed to evaluate external applicability for package update: 976933-0_neutral_PACKAGE [HRESULT= 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
2017-02-09 11:08:18, Error                 CBS    Failed to call external evaluate applicability on package: Package_for_KB976932~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.17514, Update: 976933-0_neutral_PACKAGE [HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]

2017-02-09 11:08:28, Info                  CBS    Failed to find package from aggreated XML string, package: Package_for_KB976933~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~fr-FR~6.1.7601.17514 [HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
2017-02-09 11:08:28, Info                  CBS    Failed to find package from deployment update [HRESULT = 0x80070490 -ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
2017-02-09 11:08:28, Error                 CBS    Failed to check whether package is partially installed, package: Windows7SP1-KB976933~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.17514 [HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
2017-02-09 11:08:28, Info                  CBS    Failed to evaluate external applicability for package update: 976933-0_neutral_PACKAGE [HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
2017-02-09 11:08:28, Error                 CBS    Failed to call external evaluate applicability on package: Package_for_KB976932~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.17514, Update: 976933-0_neutral_PACKAGE [HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
```

... I then searched with `regedit.exe` for 31bf3856ad364e35 and found the following entry (see [pic below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrzXu.png)) Would removing "{A8F6EABA-43E3-410F-B196-A4A38FC70C51}" from "Packages to Add" make this worse or possibly fix these errors and let me install pending updates?

[image]

Comment: Oh, and by the way, don't mind the failed updates because this is a log, not a list of available updates. Sometimes, for a failed update entry, there is another "Successful" entry upper in the log. Sometimes, a failed update is never installed because a newer replacement update is installed instead. Updates that are truly failed and never got installed reappear in Windows Update's main update list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(migrated from the comments to the question)

First I would try to reset all the Windows Update, that way it will start anew. You can use this script https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Reset-Windows-Update-Agent-d824badc  Run it As Administrator, use option 2 and 3, and when finished restart the PC.

If that does not help, I would suggest you trying to delete the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersio‌n\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\RebootRequired` (export it first to have a backup) and restart the PC again

Answer (score 1):

Per FleetCommand's comment, the "pending" and "failed" status in the Update History was somewhat misleading:

> don't mind the failed updates because this is a log, not a list of
>   available updates. Sometimes, for a failed update entry, there is
>   another "Successful" entry upper in the log. Sometimes, a failed
>   update is never installed because a newer replacement update is
>   installed instead. Updates that are truly failed and never got
>   installed reappear in Windows Update's main update list.

Per Yisroel's answer, I have downloaded and run [ResetWUEng.cmd](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Reset-Windows-Update-Agent-d824badc) (as Administrator) to reset the Updater (Option #2) so that I am current with updates (see below). I am now able to check for updates from the Control panel (without being told I need to restart) AND I no longer get the persistent reminder to restart!

Here's the main screen of the Reset Windows Update Tool - I only used option #2 but Yisroel suggests Option #3 as well:

[image]

This deleted the history along with updating components - but per FleetCommand, the history is not a very accurate record. I then used `regedit.exe` to first export a backup copy and then remove the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersio‌​n\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\RebootRequired`...

Now when I launch the Windows Update Control panel I see:

[image]

...then after pressing the "Check For Updates" button, BINGO:

[image]

...things are looking like they should again. I selected and downloaded the updates, and now this is what I see in the Control Panel:

[image]

(I only installed 4 of the 5 "Optional" updates - one was for a program I don't use.)

...After the download I restarted the computer, components were prepared after log off and prior to shut down, then installed upon rebooting. And best of all, now I can check for updates from the Windows Updater Control Panel:

[image]

...and the history is relevant again. Also of note, i hadn't seen any "Optional" updates come through before, just "Important" or "Recommended" - seems like everything is back to normal!

[image]